# jQuery display checked or unchecked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table with the first column of each row is a checkbox. Above the table are options of all/on/off which should display the rows of the table based on if the checkbox is checked or not. I will need this to work for at least 10 rows.
Here's the code:

```js
$(".parent").find("checkbox").each(function() {
 if ($(this).prop('checked')==true) { 
  var $on = $this;

 } else {
  var $off = $this;
 }

 $("#on").click(function() {
  $off.hide();
  $on.show();
 });
 
 $("#off").click(function() {
  $on.hide();
  $off.show();
 });
});
```

```css
ul li { 
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

table {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="all" data-filter="all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="on" data-filter="on">On</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="off" data-filter="off">Off</a></li>
</ul>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="parent">
            <input type="checkbox" class="box">
            <label>One</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="parent">
            <input type="checkbox" class="box">
            <label>Two</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Text</p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="box">
            <label>Three</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Text</p>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am very new to jQuery so anything helps. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Sorry. How do I filter through the rows of the table based on if they are checked or not with on/off/all buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a1jLykum/1/)

You can select all `.parent` elements that contains checked checkbox by `.has()` selector like this:

```
$('.parent').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

Comment: Hi @Andrea if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This works for the code that I gave you, but what if I had other td's in my rows? I updated my original code snippet to include them.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! var parent would just need to change to be the tr. So it would be `var parent = $('tr');`

Answer (score 0):

One option is the following:

```
// caching references to the various elements we'll
// re-use:
var on = $('#on'),
  off = $('#off'),
  all = $('#all'),
  table = $('table'),
  rows = table.find('tr'),
  inputs = table.find('input[type=checkbox]');

// binding the anonymous function as the event-handler
// for the click event:
on.click(function() {
  // hiding all <tr> elements:
  rows.hide();
  // filtering the collection of input elements of
  // type=checkbox, retaining only those that are
  // checked:
  inputs.filter(':checked')
    // finding the closest <tr> elements:
    .closest('tr')
    // and showing them:
    .show();
});

off.click(function() {
  rows.hide();
  // filtering the collection of <input> elements:
  inputs
    // retaining only those that are not checked:
    .filter(':not(":checked")')
    // finding the closest <tr> element:
    .closest('tr')
    // and showing them:
    .show();
});

all.click(function() {
  rows.show();
});
```

```js
var on = $('#on'),
  off = $('#off'),
  all = $('#all'),
  table = $('table'),
  rows = table.find('tr'),
  inputs = table.find('input[type=checkbox]');

on.click(function() {
  rows.hide();
  inputs.filter(':checked').closest('tr').show();
});

off.click(function() {
  rows.hide();
  inputs.filter(':not(":checked")').closest('tr').show();
});

all.click(function() {
  rows.show();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
table {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="all" data-filter="all">All</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="on" data-filter="on">On</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="off" data-filter="off">Off</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="parent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box">
      <label>One</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="parent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box">
      <label>Two</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="box">
      <label>Three</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```